# PomData cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml

I'm using Eclipse with maven plugin. I just downloaded project, where are some values in code taken from pom file.

```
logger.info(lf(_("Pre-init of %s v%s", PomData.NAME, PomData.VERSION)));
```

But I get error:

`PomData cannot be resolved to a variable`

How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume this is a compilation error, right? Is the project using https://github.com/SpongePowered/sponge-plugin-archetype? This seems to generate a Java class called `PomData` with the structure expected in your code.